# Combinar varios csv por clave python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tengo varios csv con solo 2 columnas, la primera tiene nombres de APIs y la segunda el número de veces que aparecen en un proceso.

Con esto, quiero unir los csv que tengo de forma que la primera columna siga siendo el nombre de las APIs y las siguientes columnas, el número de apariciones de cada uno de los csv que tengo. Además, en todos los csv no están las mismas APIs, o sea que lo que quiero es que salgan todas las que hay entre todos los csv y que cuando un proceso no lo tenga, a esa casilla se le asigne un 0.

Mi codigo ahora mismo es:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("./")
extension = 'csv'
nombres = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in nombres ], axis = 1)

combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Pero claro esto simplemente me anida las dos columnas de cada csv en uno nuevo.

Comment: Lee cada csv a un datafrane separado y usa `set_index()` para hacer que el índice sea el nombre de las apis, en cada uno de ellos. Después juntalos con `join()` o `merge()`. Eso usará los índices para juntar las filas "iguales" (y pondrá NaN si una api no está en uno de ellos).

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, con el comentario del usuario abulafia, que no me funcionaba tan sencillamente pero si que me ha sido de gran utilidad y unas búsquedas por internet, la solución a la que he recurrido ha sido la siguiente:

```
import os
import functools
import glob
import pandas as pd

#directorio = ('./')
os.chdir("./")

extension = 'csv'
dfs = [pd.read_csv(i).set_index('API') for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

print(dfs)
df = functools.reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on="API", how="outer"), dfs)

df = df.fillna(0)
df.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')

print(df)
```